# Prestashop 1.7 API - Problem with a new order

Tags: api, prestashop

External software (Baselinker) cannot create order in my Prestashop through the web service.

```
function validateOrder() on boolean in
/home/YYY/domains/XXX/public_html/classes/order/Order.php:1687 Stack trace: #0
/home/YYY/domains/XXX/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php(1566): OrderCore->addWs() #1
/home/YYY/domains/XXX/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php(1370): WebserviceRequestCore->saveEntityFromXml(201) #2
/home/YYY/domains/XXX/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php(565): WebserviceRequestCore->executeEntityPost() #3
/home/YYY/domains/XXX/public_html/webservice/dispatcher.php(87): WebserviceRequestCore->fetch('TW76KCVK825K1UC...', 'POST', 'orders', Array, false, '<?xml version="...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/YYY/domains/XXX/public_html/classes/order/Order.php on line 1687
```

Here is the part of code in Order.php on line 1687.

```
$payment_module->validateOrder($this->id_cart, Configuration::get('PS_OS_WS_PAYMENT'),
$this->total_paid, $this->payment, null, array(), null, false, $customer->secure_key);
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We could have the entire class order, as well as the parameters sent, because according to the version of PS, the class is not the same.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Integracja sklepu przez plik integracyjny".

Comment: It is my current method, however switching to API seems to be more secure way. Webservice works well except this one thing - order stays in section with abandoned carts and cannot move further.

Answer (score 0):

I checked what is in Order->addWs() and before add order should be created customer, and cart.

When creating Order you need to set and pass:

- module -> need to be name of installed payment module
- id_customer
- id_cart
- total_paid
- payment